# jdb and jde with emacs ( name unknown)

Tags: java, emacs, jde, jdb

main[1] print myVariable

com.sun.tools.example.debug.expr.ParseException: Name unknown: myVariable

myVariable = null

Any guesses as to why this might be happening? I can place breakpoints like I'm used to, but I can't access the variables.

Answer (score 7):

When you compile your code, make sure you do it debug mode:

```
javac -g *.java
```

You should then be able to print the variables during debugging.